# Efeito HOVER em uma <li> e os componentes dentro dele

Tags: html, css

Bom dia pessoal!

Eu tenho `<li>` em meu projeto, gostaria muito de usar uma imagem no lado direito de SAIR da minha `<li>`, fiz assim:

```
<ul>
    <li id="sair">Sair<div class="icons"></div></li>
</ul>
```

O meu CSS:

```
.icons{
    width: 15px;
    height: 14px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -16px;
    margin-left: 815px;
    z-index: 5;
    background-image: url("logout-px.png");
}

.icons:hover{
    width: 15px;
    height: 14px;
    background-position: 14px 0px;
    background-color: red !important;
    background-image: url("logout-px.png");
}

#sair:hover
{
    color: white;
    background-color: red !important;
    border-bottom-color: #a20000;
    border-left-color: #a20000;
    border-right-color: #ff6363;
    border-top-color: #ff6363;
    border-width: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Imagens:**

Sem `:hover`: 
[image: Sem <code>:hover</code>]

Hover com mouse no `<li>`:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Hover com mouse na `<div>`:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria algo que, apenas passando o mouse no `<li>` o feito HOVER pegasse em todos, até na `<div>`, obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Coloque a imagem diretamente no li, é bem mais fácil:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li id="sair">Sair</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
#sair {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 2px;
    background: transparent url("logout-px.png") no-repeat right center;
}
#sair:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/ypnnxg0x/)

Answer (score 2):

Para que todos os `<li>` tenham o mesmo efeito você deve aplicar um seletor da própria tag como a seguir:

```
li:hover {
// código CSS
}
```

Ao invés de:

```
#sair:hover {
// código CSS
}
```

E deixe com que os elementos dentro o `<li>` herdem do pai, ou seja, do `<li>`, por exemplo: quando o efeito `:hover` ocorrer no pai (`<li>`) os elementos filhos também herdarão as mesmas propriedades.
Por exemplo:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="sair">Sair<div class="icons">aasas</div></li>
    <!-- outros <li> -->
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu li:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: red !important;
     // outras propriedades
}

.icons {
     background-color: inherit; // Aqui está herdando a propriedade do <li> que é o pai, nesse caso, o background do ícone também vai ficar vermelho
     // outras propriedades
}
```

Fazendo assim, você pode até descartar o seletor `.icons:hover` para este menu.

Answer (score 1):

Se você deseja mudar o comportamento quando houver `hover` na `li`, do elemento filho, que no seu caso é a `div` com classe `.icons`, você pode fazer:

```
#sair:hover .icons {
   ...
}
```

**Veja um exemplo:**

```css
ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:5px;
}
ul li {
    width:60px;
    padding:2px;
}
.icons{
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display:inline-block;  
    background-image: url("http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/2354/dusseldorf/16/logout.png");
    margin-left: 2px;
}

#sair:hover
{
    color: white;
    background-color: red !important;
    border-bottom-color: #a20000;
    border-left-color: #a20000;
    border-right-color: #ff6363;
    border-top-color: #ff6363;
    border-width: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#sair:hover .icons {
     /*Altera a imagem de background*/
     background-image: url("http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/2146/realistik_reloaded/16/exit.png");
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li id="sair">
      Sair
      <div class="icons"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Você pode também utilizar ícones CSS para este fim, como por exemplo [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/), veja um exemplo:**

```css
ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:5px;
}
ul li {
    width:40px;
    padding:2px;
    font-size:14px;
}
ul li:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul>
    <li id="sair">Sair <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i></li>
</ul>
```